# How to get eip without stack in x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I want to set `esp` depend on `eip`, so I can't use stack. How can I get the value of `eip` without stack.

Comment: Some context might be helpful here. Why can't you use the stack?

Comment: If you are using absolute code model than you can ask compiler or calcolate from offset.

Comment: @RossRidge: I want to get which address grub2 loads a kernel to. I don't know where the stack can place and which memory zone is used. So I want to setup up the stack near by the code. But the `eip` is unknown.

Comment: @GJ.: I don't know which address can be used. So I  can only use relative address.

Comment: That still doesn't really make sense. Why isn't there an already a valid stack for you to use? In what context is your code actually running? Is it a bootsector, a GRUB2 module, an ordinary Linux process? I think you've made the mistake of not asking your real question. Ultimately what are you trying to accomplish? Why do you even need to know what address the kernel gets loaded?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nope, it's impossible in x86-32. EIP is only leaked from the CPU through the `call` instruction or on interrupts/traps. All of these methods will use the stack in one way or another.

(By contrast, x86-64 allows you to `lea` relative to `rip`.)

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot change ESP, you must be executing in some context in which an interrupt is not possible, e.g., some interrupt routine or context switching code, or you have garbage in ESP.  (In the latter case, I suggest you revise your code so ESP always points into an area usable for a stack; this isn't hard to arrange in practice and prevents very strange bugs in code when using a garbage ESP).

In this case, you can encode the EIP value you want into a mov immediate instruction operand.  You can write the following in assembler to "get EIP":

```
   mov   ecx, offset $    ; different assemblers use different syntax for "current address"
```

or

```
   mov   ecx, offset L1
L1: ...
```

If you are not writing in assembler, you can generate the binary equivalent of the above using the $B8 "mov" opcode, providing the right register value, and filling in the immediate32 value with the location in which you place the mov instruction.

Comment: Actually when the user process receives an interrupt, the state is pushed onto the *kernel* (ring 0) stack. So the user ESP could very well be garbage and things will still run.

Comment: @NayukiMinase: Assuming that the interrupt vector is configured to execute in ring 0, but of course that is the most common configuration

Comment: @NayukiMinase: Hmm.  Interesting, an old guy learns a new detail. Lesson: always check the reference manual.  OK, then ESP could contain complete garbage and the call solution would not work because you could get a PUSH to a garbage location.   I actually do a LOT of context switching in x86 machine code; I avoid this problem by always insisting the ESP point into *some* valid area usable as a stack. (Means I don't have to worry about the problem, either!).   OP should clarify his situation.

Comment: @Ira Baxter: No problemo, it's nothing to be embarrassed about. I was able to make this comment only because I *have* gone through the tedious process of writing a kernel-mode interrupt handler, reading the Intel manual and carefully dissecting the struct that the CPU pushes onto the kernel stack. =)

Comment: @NayukiMinase: not embarrased, just old and leaning too much on my background instead of reference docs :-{  Actually,  I wanted my switchable threads to operate in a user space without bad surprises, thus the always safe-stack-stunt.  This partly to avoid having to know how kernal traps work but mostly to completely avoid advice I got long ago when I started my switchable threads stuff, of "well, you should modify the kernal code to do that..."  (Yipes!). My sympathies for your pain, and glad I ducked.